Import PDF data to excel
I am trying to import PDF data into Excel, recording a macro I get this code and works perfectly, but when I try to replace the "pathFile" with a variable, I get an error:

The supplied file path must be valid absolute path

It appears I don't know how to handle the  "" "" if I replace couple, syntax error appears, if I remove all and let only variable same error, and if put 3 double quotes syntax error raises.
How can I chance this path with a variable?
Code:
Sub test()

Dim file As String
pathFile = "C:\Users\Documents\Sample.pdf"

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Page001 (2)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(""**C:\Documents\Sample.pdf**""), [Implementation=""1.3""])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Page1 = Source{[Id=""Page001""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Page1, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Heade" & _
        "rs"",{{""Column1"", Int64.Type}, {""DocuSign Envelope ID: 3A4A0FCB-6371-49E0-B015-D8F6EFD7CC8F"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type te" & _
        "xt}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type date}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Page001 (2)"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Page001 (2)]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Page001__2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub

The only thing I need is run this code using filePath as variable.

...File.Contents(""" & pathFile & """), [Implementation...

No way!!! I have literally 4 hours trying adding, removing, changing and other things and never try this, now is working perfectly, thanks a lot Tim!!!

Solution was:
...File.Contents(""" & pathFile & """), [Implementation... –
As Tim Williams comment.
Apr 4 at 22:48
